# How can I use a view and a web view together - Android

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

how can I use a view and a webview together? ex: 
I have a login screen, where native use when login I access the webview, and finally I would like a button which returned to the login screen.

I dont know the name of this resource type. Just like to know how I can start.

Thanks!

Login:

[image]

Webview

[image]

When I press "SAIR" ( Logout ), I need back to Login! I don't know, how I can do it!

Comment: Do you want to overlay a View on top of a WebView?

Comment: Yeah, I do login, it's okay, open up the webview. I don't know how I can back to Login on the Webview!

Comment: More description/a diagram would be very helpful to other to understand what you need.

Comment: @Michael Krause I'd update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly,  you can put your login screen and WebView to FrameLayout together and use something like this:

```html
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/web_view">
    </WebView>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--Your login screen here-->
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

```java
// When you logout
loginView.bringToFornt();
// When you login
webView.bringToFront();
```